# WebBrowser Control does not draw until I resize the parent Form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to use a WebBrowser control inside a popup Form in my app in lieu of a Label. I wrote a function that returns the Form as a variable, given a title and body text.
It works well - the Form displays correctly and resizes appropriately.  However the WebBrowser Control won't draw anything until I resize the Form.

I tried adding `WebBrowser.Refresh()` but that did not help.

The function that creates the popup Form:

```
Public Function PopupHtmlForm(title As String, body As String, Optional formSize As Size = Nothing) As Form
    Dim formWidth = IIf(formSize = Nothing, 300, formSize.Width)
    Dim formHeight = IIf(formSize = Nothing, 500, formSize.Height)

    Dim frm = New Form
    frm.Size() = New Size(formWidth, formHeight)
    frm.Icon = Main.Icon
    frm.Text = title

    Dim htmlBody = New WebBrowser With {
        .DocumentText = body,
        .Location = New Point(5, 5),
        .Width = frm.ClientSize.Width - 10,
        .Height = frm.ClientSize.Height - 15,
        .BackColor = Color.White,
        .AutoSize = True,
        .MaximumSize = New Size(frm.ClientSize.Width - 10, 0)
    }

    frm.Controls.Add(htmlBody)
    frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
    frm.Location = New Size(1000, 50)
    frm.AutoScroll = True
    If frm.VerticalScroll.Visible Then htmlBody.MaximumSize = New Size(frm.ClientSize.Width - 10 - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth, 0)
    AddHandler frm.SizeChanged, Sub()
                                    htmlBody.MaximumSize = New Size(frm.ClientSize.Width - 10, 0)
                                    htmlBody.Width = frm.ClientSize.Width - 10
                                    htmlBody.Height = frm.ClientSize.Height - 15
                                End Sub

    htmlBody.Refresh() 'Added to try to get the control to draw
    Return frm

End Function
```

The calling code:

```
Dim lorem As String = "..."
PopupHtmlForm("This is a popup", lorem).ShowDialog()
```

You can see the result below - the blank dialog Form can move, but as soon as it resizes, it finally displays the content:

[image]

From process of elimination, it appears that changing the `htmlBody.Height` is what triggers the redraw, but when I try to do that before the Form is shown, the content of `DocumentText` still doesn't appear.

Is there a way to make the WebBrowser Control draw without this user interaction?

Comment: `Dim htmlBody as New WebBrowser() With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill, .DocumentText = body} frm.Controls.Add(htmlBody)`. Remove all the rest. You have some problems there, as setting the `Location` Property to a `Size` value and wrong measures taken at the wrong time.  You can remove the `SizeChanged` handler. -- I don't know what this is: `frm.Size()` (Typo?). Also, `If formSize = Nothing Then formSize = New Size(300, 500) frm.Size = formSize`

Comment: You may consider using `WebView2`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/ for more information.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks - I had adapted this from a function I made that used a label, but your simplification solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

When you call the form try this:

```
    Dim lorem As String = "..."
    Dim PopupForm As Form = PopupHtmlForm("This is a popup", lorem)

    PopupForm.Height += 1
    PopupForm.Height -= 1
    PopupForm.ShowDialog()
```

I know this is not the best approach, but it still works.

Comment: Thanks - this does work! Ultimately I went with @Jimi's comment solution which had the added benefit of simplifying my code